# Clear all writers' permissions in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am using scripts to draw the list of permitted writers to a document `new_ID` from a list in `sheet_roles` using

```
for (var j = 3; j<=last_row_role; j++) {
  if (range_roles.getCell(j, 4).getValue() != ''){
  add_Writer_Silent(new_ID, sheet_roles.getRange(j,3).getValue())
  }
}
```

where

```
 function add_Writer_Silent(docId, userEmail) {
  var permissionResource = {
    role: 'writer',   //can also have owner / organizer / fileOrganizer / writer / commenter / reader
    type: 'user',
    value: userEmail
  };
  var optionalArgs = {
    sendNotificationEmails: false,
    supportsAllDrives: true
  };
  Drive.Permissions.insert(permissionResource, docId, optionalArgs);
}
```

I would like to write another function that would update the list of writers. To do so, I need to clear the permissions list first and I am unable to find a way to do it in `Permissions`.

Can someone help me identify a way to remove all writers' permissions from a file using scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to first list all the permissions in the file and then get the ones with the role "writer" using its ID, you can try this:

```
function remove_permissions(docId) {
  var optionalArgs = {
    supportsAllDrives: true
  };
  
  var permissions = Drive.Permissions.list(docId, optionalArgs); //Saving all permissions in one Object.
  for(i=0; i< permissions.items.length; i++){ //Iterating through all items in the object.
    if(permissions.items[i].role == "writer"){
      Drive.Permissions.remove(docId, permissions.items[i].id);
    }
  }
}
```

Reference:

- [Drive API Permissions: list.](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/list)
- [Drive API Permissions: delete.](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/delete)